# Get the value of Select dropdown list when the value sent by the form and that appearing in the dropdown list are different

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a form which has the following `Select` dropdown list.

```
<select name="some_options" id="some_options">
@foreach(options as option)
<option value="{{$option->id}}">{{$option->value}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Here , the data are being sent from the **database** via the **Controller**

The **Select** data look like this

```
<select name="some_options" id="some_options">
<option value="opt001">Value 1</option>
<option value="opt002">Value 2</option>
<option value="opt003">Value 3</option>
<option value="opt004">Value 4</option>
<option value="opt005">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Now, I have another `disabled` field which should get the value once the user changes the `select` `option`

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="some_options_cng" disabled>
</div>
```

**My Javascript code**

```
 var opt = $('#some_options').val();

$('#some_options').on('change',function(){

opt = $('#some_options').val();

$('#some_options_cng').val(opt);


});
```

*Now, the value in the `<disabled>` input field shows as*

**opt001** or **opt002** and so on.

*I want to show values as*

**Value 1** or   **Value 2**.

How do I do it?

Comment: `opt = $('#some_options option:selected').text();`

Comment: its not the value its the content of it as Mohamed-Yousef is illustrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work.

```
$('#some_options').change(function(){
        var opt = $("#some_options").find(":selected").text(); //This line of code is 
                                                               //important
        $('#some_options_cng').val(opt);
      })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#some_options').change(function(){
    var opt = $("#some_options").find(":selected").text();
    $('#some_options_cng').val(opt);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="some_options" id="some_options">
<option value="opt001">Value 1</option>
<option value="opt002">Value 2</option>
<option value="opt003">Value 3</option>
<option value="opt004">Value 4</option>
<option value="opt005">Value 5</option>
</select>
<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="some_options_cng" disabled>
</div>
```